# What should define a question as too broad, the number of requirments or the number of possible solutions?

Tags: discussion

A question can still have more than 10 requirements and too many or easy to find answers.

In the same time, a question with only 2 requirements might don’t have any existing device at all or at least very unlikely to exist *(for example [this one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65287/hardware-recommendations/72049#72049))*.

So for me it’s obvious it’s the number of possible answers and how they are easy to find that should define wheather a question is too broad or not.
However it makes https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/review far more difficult **:‑)**. Because it require to try to answer the question first and possibly write comments and wait for an answer instead of overlook it and click on the close button *(or not doing so for questions which are really too broad)*. **:‑)**

If there’s a correlation between the number of requirements and the number of products available matching the specification, should we require a minimum number of requirements *(please note it tends de‑facto applied like robots do)* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it can be that clear cut. It has to be a combination of both. The number of requirements has a correlation to the number of products available matching the specification - it's not a causal relationship, but more general.

- Few requirements are often the signal of a broad question. These need closer review - if the requirements narrow it down to just a few products, that's fine.
- Lots of requirements don't generally need as much of a close eye, since they have a much stronger correlation with few matching products.

I *don't* think we should be requiring a minimum number of requirements, though, precisely because of this - there are valid questions with only one or two requirements, that still have very few products available matching the definition. Fortunately, we're humans, not robots - we can apply common sense rather than just metrics when reviewing posts.

Comment: I recognize I asked this question because of [this one](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2100/1808) *(3 close votes)*. Many questions on the original area51 show no correlations between number of requirements and the number of possible answers.

Comment: @user2284570 Our scope has changed since the Area 51 proposal; these aren't good examples to use. That said, I do think your question is on topic, and I've dropped a comment correcting the user you were interacting with in the comments; he seems to have had a misinterpretation of our scope.

Comment: So if a few products fit the criteria that's good enough? Someone told me that requirements must be so specific that only 1 product should fit.

Comment: @JimThio If you *can* have enough requirements to narrow it down to one product, that's awesome. If not, it's okay if there are a few products that match, as long as it's a *few*.